# How to fix Shopware images import error - Ordernumber and image are required

Tags: xml, shopware

I have read the examples from shopware.com for Image Import via XML File 
[Images.xml](https://community.shopware.com/files/DataImportExport/Images.xml) .

Then i created this XML below, upload and got this error:

**Import error: Ordernumber and image are required.** [image: Ordernumber and image are required]

How could i fix that?

### My XML:

```
<Root>
    <Header>
        <HeaderChild/>
    </Header>
    <images>
        <image>
        <orderNumber>020201</orderNumber>
        <image>http://1808280148.net/01.jpg</image>
        <main>1</main>
        <description>greensea</description>
        <position>1</position>
        <width>0</width>
        <height>0</height>
        <relations></relations>
        <thumbnail>1</thumbnail>
        </image>
    </images>
</Root>
```

*By the way: http://1808280148.net is is fictitiously invented.
Previously I installed the shop [shopware 5.4.6][4], then imported categories and addet articles. 
I also have access to the database via phpmyadmin. A snapshot of a similar configuration installation as virtualbox image you could also find here: https://github.com/sl5net/lubuntu-shopware-stack*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the profile - in the default profile the column has the name "ordernumber", but in your XML-file it is "orderNumber". Please make sure, that the names match.

There are two possibile solutions:

- Change the name of the directly in the XML (orderNumber ->
  ordernumber)
- Duplicate the profile and change the name in the profile (ordernumber
  -> orderNumber)

Comment: i change tag names "orderNumber" to "ordernumber" and it works.